# “Disprove” Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: popularity-contest, math, underhanded

Write a program, in the language of your choice, that *appears* to successfully find a counterexample to [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).  That is, find integers *a*, *b*, *c* > 0 and *n* > 2 such that a<sup>n</sup> + b<sup>n</sup> = c<sup>n</sup>.

Of course, you can't *really* do it, unless there's a flaw in Andrew Wiles' proof.  I mean *fake it*, by relying on

- integer overflow
- floating-point rounding error
- undefined behavior
- data types with unusual definitions of addition, exponentiation, or equality
- compiler/interpreter bugs
- or something along those lines.

You may hard-code some or all of the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, or `n`, or search for them by doing loops like `for a = 1 to MAX`.

This isn't a code golf; it's a contest to find clever and subtle solutions.

Comment: actually, you can have ones as all of them besides the exponent, which has to be 3 or higher. So, 1^3+1^3=1^3 its that simple.

Comment: @Siver: 1³+1³=2; 1³=1; 2≠1

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### J

Actually, Fermat did make quite a blunder: It's actually wrong for any b, c or n if a is 1:

```
   1^3 + 4^3 = 5^3
1
   1^4 + 5^4 = 11^4
1
   1^9 + 3^9 = 42^9
1
```

> Maybe just maybe, Fermat's precedence rules weren't strictly right to left.

Comment: +1 Strictly right to left indeed. Just for people who read left to right; normal notation for the last one would be `1^(9 + (3^(9 = (42^9))))`

Comment: Ah...so *any* expression that starts with `1^` evaluates to 1.

Comment: Sneaky, my brain was about to melt until I saw @TheRare's comment

Comment: @german_guy Glad to be of help.

Comment: Is this an intended feature of J? This is the kind of thing that would really drive people insane.

Comment: @qwr In J, all evaluation is from right to left, with some exceptions. It sounds weird but is actually pretty neat.

Comment: @dan04 Not strictly speaking true. `1^i.5` evaluates to `1 1 1 1 1`.

Answer (score 36):

## TI-Basic

```
1782^12+1841^12=1922^12
```

Output (true)

```
1
```

Comment: @dan04 What is the reference here?

Comment: http://photos1.blogger.com/blogger/4608/663/1600/homer.fermat.jpg

Comment: I saw that episode so often, never noticed that. Nice catch!

Comment: This answer only works as written with TI-89-flavor TI-Basic. On a TI-84+ SE, the code has a syntax error, because that version of TI-Basic does not allow spaces. But the answer still works on an older calculator if you remove spaces, writing `1782^12+1841^12=1922^12`.

Comment: If I evaluate `1782^12+1841^12` or `1922^12` separately, each outputs “2.541210259e39”, suggesting a floating-point rounding error. But if I try to view the hidden significant digits, `fPart((1782^12+1841^12)/10^33)` outputs `.2586147`, while `fPart((1922^12)/10^33)` outputs `.2593147`. I’m confused how the calculator made the rounding mistake for the large numbers, yet outputs different numbers when the large numbers are re-divided.

Comment: Doesn't the TI-89 work in exact mode by default if you don't have decimal points in your numbers?

Comment: +1 for using TI-Basic, it was my first programming language :)

Comment: Calculators are good at math. This *obviously* must be true.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall That's the irony, a calculator failing a simple math problem

Answer (score 35):

## Java

This Fermat guy must have been sleeping. I get hundreds of solutions to the equations. I merely converted my Excel formula to a Java program.

```java
public class FermatNoMore {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 3; n < 6; n++)
            for (int a = 1; a < 1000; a++)
                for (int b = 1; b < 1000; b++)
                    for (int c = 1; c < 1000; c++)
                        if ((a ^ n + b ^ n) == (c ^ n))
                            System.out.println(String.format("%d^%d + %d^%d = %d^%d", a, n, b, n, c, n));
    }
}
```

> The `^` operator actually means XOR in Java, as opposed to exponentiation in typical plain-text

Comment: Any chance on an elaboration on why this works?

Comment: @Vality: `^` in Java is xor, not power.

Comment: this technically works on almost any C-based languages

Answer (score 19):

### C++

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

unsigned long pow(int a, int p) {
  unsigned long ret = a;

  for (int i = 1; i < p; ++i)
    ret *= a;

  return ret;
}

bool fermat(int n) {
  // surely we can find a counterexample with 0 < a,b,c < 256;
  unsigned char a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

  // don't give up until we've found a counterexample
  while (true) {
    if (pow(a, n) + pow(b, n) == pow(c, n)) {
      // found one!
      return true;
    }

    // make sure we iterate through all positive combinations of a,b,c
    if (!++a) {
      a = 1;
      if (!++b) {
        b = 1;
        if (!++c)
          c = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (fermat(std::atoi(argv[1])))
   std::cout << "Found a counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem" << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with `clang++ -O3 -o fermat fermat.cpp`, tested with `Ubuntu clang version 3.4.1-1~exp1 (branches/release_34) (based on LLVM 3.4.1)`:

```
./fermat 3
Found a counterexample to Fermat's Last Theorem
```

We obviously found a, b, c > 0 so that a<sup>3</sup> + b<sup>3</sup> = c<sup>3</sup> (this also works for n = 4, 5, 6, ...).

> Printing a, b and c might prove a bit difficult though ...

Comment: Needs `-lstdc++` to build on my PC.  But do make sure to include the `-O3` flag.  It doesn't work on `-O0`.

Comment: @dan04: Oops, forgot the `++` in `clang++`.

Comment: By the way, this is not a compiler bug. C (and C++) standard allows to do anything here, as `val.u` can overflow (it would be different if it would be `uint32_t` instead). Besides, this code also uses `union` in incorrect way (according to standard, you cannot write to one field, and read the other field), but this is allowed by many compilers (according to their documentation).

Comment: @xfix The same thing happens when `val.u` is made `uint32_t` or the overflow is checked. In fact, I just used the union to make the code a bit shorter (otherwise it'd require extra checks to correctly increment/reset a, b and c). I've changed the code to remove the union, and it still produces the same output.

Comment: The reason this is allowed is a section of the C++ standard that says:

A loop that, outside of the for-init-statement in the case of a for statement,

* makes no calls to library I/O functions, and
* does not access or modify volatile objects, and
* performs no synchronization operations (1.10) or atomic operations (Clause 29)

may be assumed by the implementation to terminate.

Comment: @dan04 That exact wording has actually been removed from the standard in a later draft, see US 38 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3196.htm - but of course, it's only been generalized. This is the reason why printing out `a,b,c` (or anything, for that matter) in `fermat()` makes the function never return.

Comment: Argh I was so going to post that one. For anybody who's confused: John Regehr has a nice explanation [here](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/161).

Comment: @Voo That's not too useful without a link. John Regehr, if I even found the right blog, has 273 posts tagged computer science.

Comment: @raptortech97 You missed the link that's under the word here in my comment :-) It's post 161 from the URL though if I'd to guess.

Comment: @Voo Oh yeah now I feel really stupid...

Answer (score 13):

## Java

It looks like the theorem holds for n=3, but I found counterexamples for n=4:

```
public class Fermat {
    public static int p4(final int x) {
        return x * x * x * x;
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(p4(64) + p4(496) == p4(528));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Explanation:

> Even if the numbers seem small, they overflow when raised to the 4th power. In reality, 64<sup>4</sup> + 496<sup>4</sup> = 528<sup>4</sup> - 2<sup>34</sup>, but 2<sup>34</sup> becomes 0 when restricted to int (32 bits).

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: @AnubianNoob done

Answer (score 9):

## Python

```
import math
print math.pow(18014398509481984,3) + math.pow(1, 3) \
      == math.pow(18014398509481983,3)
```

> Who says that *c* must be greater than *a* and *b*?

Comment: It prints `True` because math.pow returns floating-point numbers, and these do not have enough precision to get the correct answer, `False`.

Answer (score 5):

## GolfScript

```
# Save the number read from STDIN in variable N and format for output.

:N"n="\+

{
  [{100rand)}3*] # Push an array of three randomly selected integers from 1 to 100.
  .{N?}/         # Compute x**N for each of the three x.
  +=!            # Check if the sum of the topmost two results equals the third.
}{;}while        # If it doesn't, discard the array and try again.

# Moar output formatting.

~]["a=""\nb=""\nc="""]]zip
```

This approach finds a bunch of different solutions. For example:

```
$ golfscript fermat.gs <<< 3
n=3
a=43
b=51
c=82
```

#### How it works

> The first line should start with a `~` to interpret the input. Instead of, e.g., the number 3 , variable `N` contains the string `3\n`.
>  While `2 3 ?` calculates <sup>3</sup>, `2 N ?` pushes the index of a character with ASCII code 2 in `N` (-1 for not found).
>  This way, `43 N ?` and `82 N ?` push `-1` and `51 N ?` pushes `0` (51 is the ASCII character code of `3`).
>  Since `-1 + 0 = -1`, the condition is satisfied and `(43,51,82)` is a "solution".

Answer (score 4):

## C

Well of course you folks are all finding counterexamples, you keep on getting integer overflows. Plus, you're being really slow by iterating on c as well. This is a much better way to do it!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  double a, b, c;
  for (a = 2; a < 1e100; a *= 2) {
    for (b = 2; b < 1e100; b *= 2) {
      c = pow(pow(a, 3) + pow(b, 3), 1.0/3);
      if (c == floor(c)) {
        printf("%f^3 + %f^3 == %f^3\n", a, b, c);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

> `double` might be great on the range, but it's still a bit lacking in precision...

Answer (score 4):

## C

We all hate integer overflows, so we'll use a small exponent `n` and some floating point conversions. But still the theorem would not hold for `a = b = c = 2139095040`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int a, b, c;
int n;

int disprove(int a, int b, int c, int n)
{
    // Integers are so prone to overflow, so we'll reinforce them with this innocent typecast.
    float safe_a = *((float *)&a);
    float safe_b = *((float *)&b);
    float safe_c = *((float *)&c);

    return pow(safe_a, n) + pow(safe_b, n) == pow(safe_c, n);
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    a = b = c = 2139095040;
    n = rand() % 100 + 3;

    printf("Disproved for %d, %d, %d, %d: %s\n", a, b, c, n, disprove(a, b, c, n) ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Output:

`Disproved for 2139095040, 2139095040, 2139095040, 42: yes`

`Disproved for 2139095040, 2139095040, 2139095040, 90: yes`

> In IEEE 754, the number 2139095040, or 0x7F800000, represents positive infinity in single-precision floating point types. All `pow(...)` calls would return +Infinity, and +Infinity equals +Infinity. An easier task would be to disprove the Pythagorean theorem by using 0x7F800001 (Quiet NaN) which is not equal to itself according to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript

```js
var a, b, c, MAX_ITER = 16;
var n = 42;
var total = 0, error = 0;

for(a = 1 ; a <= MAX_ITER ; a++) {
  for(b = 1 ; b <= MAX_ITER ; b++) {
    for(c = 1 ; c <= MAX_ITER ; c++) {
      total++;
      if(Math.pow(a, n) + Math.pow(b, n) == Math.pow(c, n)) {
        error++;
        console.log(a, b, c);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log("After " + total + " calculations,");
console.log("I got " + error + " errors but Fermat ain't one.");
```

42 is magic, you know.

```
> node 32696.js
After 2176 calculations,
I got 96 errors but Fermat ain't one.
```

And also Wiles ain't one.

> Javascript `Number` is not big enough.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL

To disprove this Fermat guy's theorem, we just need to find a counter example.
It seems, he was super lazy, and only tried it for really small permutation. In fact, he wasn't even trying. I found a counter example in just 0 < a,b,c < 15 and 2 < e < 15. Sorry I'm a golfer at heart so I'll ungolf this code later!

```
with T(e)as(select 1e union all select (e+1) from T where e<14)select isnull(max(1),0)FROM T a,T b,T c,T e where e.e>2 and power(a.e,e.e)+power(b.e,e.e)=power(c.e,e.e)
```

Returns 1, meaning we found a counter example!

> The trick is that while the first e looks like an alias, it actually is a sneaky way of changing the data type of e from an int to a floating point type equivalent to a double. By the time we got to 14 we are beyond the precision of a floating point number so we can add 1 to it and we still don't lose anything. The minification is a nice excuse to explain away my seemingly silly double declaration of a column alias in the rcte. If I didn't do this it would overflow long before we got to 14^14.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

It appears this guy was onto something alright. Onto drugs if you ask me. Given the constraints, no set of values can be found for which the theorem holds true.

```
var a = 1,
    b = 1,
    c = 1,
    n = 3,
    lhs = (a^n + b^n),
    rhs = c^n;

alert(lhs === rhs);
```

> As in Java, the `^` operator is the bitwise XOR operator in JavaScript. The correct way to calculate the power of a number is to use Math.pow.

Comment: For Fermat, the exponent(`n`) has to be `>= 3`.

Comment: Good point, the code still works though :)

Answer (score 0):

## Another BASIC counterexample

```
10 a = 858339
20 b = 2162359
30 c = 2162380
40 IF (a^10 + b^10) = c^10 THEN
50   PRINT "Fermat disproved!"
60 ENDIF
```